# How to Add Spring Security HTTP Response Headers

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Starting with **Spring 3.2** I can simply add this to my security xml:

```
 <security:headers>
    <security:frame-options
            policy="SAMEORIGIN" />
</security:headers>
```

But this is not supported in **Spring version 3.1**, any workaround for this without having to upgrade the version?

This is documentation for version 3.1:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/reference/springsecurity.html

Comment: You can set custom header in Controller
 response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter` implements logic behind this configuration. It was introduced in Spring 3.2, nothing similar exist prior to that version.

If you want to implement this yourself, you can use a simple filter:

```
public class XFrameOptionsHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

You need to create a bean for this class in your application context:

```
<bean id="xFrameOptionsHeaderFilter" class="your.package.XFrameOptionsHeaderFilter"/>
```

And then register the filter in your `web.xml`:

```
<filter>  
    <filter-name>xFrameOptionsHeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>xFrameOptionsHeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: tnx very nice answer but I cant seem to get it working, I see the bean is loaded but method is not called when I make a request. any ideas what might be missing?

Comment: Maybe you declared the bean in the wrong place? You should put it in your app-context, the one that is used in `contextConfigLocation`, not your servlet context.